# Remove quotes from a list of strings (that are supposed to be tuples)

Tags: python

I am pulling out a row from a file. Row looks like this:

```
['(27.0, 168.0)', '(32.0, 550.0)', '(88.0, 835.0)', '(46.0, 660.0)', '(38.0, 430.0)', '(34.0, 285.0)', '(72.0, 701.0)', '(29.0, 434.0)', '(0, 2)']
```

Is there a way to convert those strings into tuples? I tried `x.strip() for x in row` but it didn`t help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you pulling them from the file, can you show us the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you ?

```
import ast

string = "['(27.0, 168.0)', '(32.0, 550.0)', '(88.0, 835.0)', '(46.0, 660.0)', '(38.0, 430.0)', '(34.0, 285.0)', '(72.0, 701.0)', '(29.0, 434.0)', '(0, 2)']"
string = string.replace("'", "")
string = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

The output is :

```
In : string
Out: 
[(27.0, 168.0),
 (32.0, 550.0),
 (88.0, 835.0),
 (46.0, 660.0),
 (38.0, 430.0),
 (34.0, 285.0),
 (72.0, 701.0),
 (29.0, 434.0),
 (0, 2)]

In : type(string)
Out: list

In : [type(x) for x in string]
Out: [tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple, tuple]
```

The `ast` module evaluates strings which I think is what you're looking for if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yup, that did a trick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If your question is solved, please mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
a = ['(27.0, 168.0)', '(32.0, 550.0)', '(88.0, 835.0)', '(46.0, 660.0)', '(38.0, 430.0)', '(34.0, 285.0)', '(72.0, 701.0)', '(29.0, 434.0)', '(0, 2)']
b = [make_tuple(x.strip()) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using `eval`.

```
# bad practice
a = ['(27.0, 168.0)', '(32.0, 550.0)', '(88.0, 835.0)', '(46.0, 660.0)', '(38.0, 430.0)', '(34.0, 285.0)', '(72.0, 701.0)', '(29.0, 434.0)', '(0, 2)']
b = [eval(tuple_str.strip()) for tuple_str in a]
```

**UPDATE**

As you can see in the comments below, it is safer to use `literal_eval`.

Comment: `eval` isn't necessary here, and should probably be avoided in this case.

Comment: @WillDaSilva Why do you think that should be avoided?

Comment: In the question it states the input is coming from a file. Since we don't know if we can trust the source of the file, we should treat it as if it could contain malicious code that we absolutely do not want to call `eval` on. By using `literal_eval` from the `ast` module, we don't have to worry about problems like code injection. It's safer, and just as simple.

Comment: @WillDaSilva  I got it. I agree with you. Thank you for being kind enough to explain.